# spring security ldaps authentization

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl, ldap

This method let's me log in active directory server.
@Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

```
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                "ldap://qwerty:389");
        contextSource.setBase("DC=abc,DC=com");
        contextSource.setUserDn("user");
        contextSource.setPassword("pass");
        contextSource.setReferral("follow");
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth
                .ldapAuthentication();

        ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.userSearchFilter("(&(sAMAccountName={0}))").userSearchBase("")
                .contextSource(contextSource);
    }
}
```

In my app I have to use ldap over ssl, so i changed port number to 636 and ldap to ldaps, but now i can't log in.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't login" ? Is there a error message or a logon denied, or...?

Comment: there is no error, login denied

Comment: What does it say on server side (ads)?